# Modify contents in foreach

Tags: c#, arraylist, structure, casting

I tend to use ArrayLists of structures. It is then very easy to cycle through the list with a foreach.

The problem I have is I cant use a foreach to modify the structures contents and have to use a for and messy typecasts.

```
((dataStructure)files[x]).name = here;
```

Is there a tidier way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this sounds simplistic but **[just say no to mutable value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)**.

They're almost *never* the right solution to the problem. There are a *very* few exceptions, but classes are almost *always* the way to go.

In addition, if you're really using an `ArrayList` then you'll be incurring an unboxing cost already... (As Konrad says, if you can use .NET 2.0 then use generics.)

If you really insist on using mutable structures, then use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`. But please, please change to classes anyway.

Comment: Jon... I think you should just put a disclaimer in every post you write about mutable types :D

Comment: i need to store various details of all the hosts that i have discovered and i need to be able to cycle through and modify them. how shoudl i be doing this?

Comment: Use a class instead of a struct.

Comment: Have a list of instances of the class.

Comment: I'll start doing that then. I assumed structs werent that different to classes as they seem pretty similar.

Comment: No, they behave very differently. I *strongly* recommend that you get a good beginner's guide to C# - you'll run into some really weird problems before you understand value types vs reference types.

Comment: Ive got a c# book which ive read most of. I didnt mean that they are the same as clearly they are not. They appear similar as they can both have variables and methods. Ive come from an embedded c background where you store data in structs, so you can see how it might feel a bit strange to be storing data in classes

Comment: What I'm saying is that the difference is really, really important. Try to forget you ever knew C :)

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is: don't use an untyped `ArrayList`, these types are deprecated in favour of the generic types in `System.Collections.Generic`. In your case: [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

You still can't use it in conjunction with a `foreach` loop to modify structure values but at least you don't have to cast.

Comment: Lists do look like a much better idea

Comment: If you're stuck with your ArrayLists for some reason (they get returned by some API that you don't have control over) then use the Cast<T> extension method for ArrayList to convert them into an IEnumerable<T>. IEnumerable<Foo> foo = foo1.Cast<Foo>();

Answer (score 1):

Use the **generic** version of `ArrayList`: `List<DataStructure>`.

This way things look a lot better:

```
files[x].name = here;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are cases where `List <T>` also is not useful. In those cases the oldest trick in the manual works. Instead of `foreach`, you should use while loop:

```
while (listItem.Count >0)
{
//do operation with 0th element of List Item always like
 deletefunc(lisItem[0]);
}
```